# evaluate the limit $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{h(x)}{g(x)}$

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity, limits-without-lhopital

[image: here is the picture of book solution which i didn't understand]evaluate this limit $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{cos^2(1-cos^2(1-cos^2(1-cos^2(.....1...\cos^2 x)).....)}{sin(\pi(\frac{\sqrt{x+4}-2}{x}))}$$

i solved it by by assuming both the individual limit exists and i used limit quotient rule,*am i correct?*
$$\frac{\lim {h(x)}}{\lim {g(x)}}$$

then i applied l'hopitals rule for $ g(x)$
by assuming it to be continous :
$$\sin\pi(\lim_{x\to 0}{\frac{\sqrt{x+4}-2}{x})}$$

we can see it to be $0/0$ form *i don't know was this correct?*

then i got my answer. now are my steps correct?

and any other way of solving is welcomed.

**EDIT**

This question i got from comments.Can the numerator have infinitely many iterations of ff? And should its limit still be 1 in this case?

Comment: How many iterations of the function do you have in the numerator?  (that is, *what* is the numerator?)

Comment: numerator is $h(x)$ *i mean that $cos^2$ terms*

Comment: ? I do not understand. Defining $f(t) = \cos^2(1-u)$, is it $f(u)$, $f(f(u))$, , $f(f(f(u)))$? How many iterations of $f$ is there?

Comment: number is not given it is just the same pattern *as given in my book*

Comment: Can you give the reference of the book, or better maybe a picture or a link to the exercise? I am still not sure I understand how the quantity considered is even defined.

Comment: se when ${x\to 0}$ ${\cos^2 x \to 1}$ therefore all terms in this manner become 1 and then $h(x)$ becomes 1 and sorry that book i think is not available on internet

Comment: $\cos^2(x) = 1-x^2 + o(x^2)$, $\cos^2(1-\cos^2(x)) = 1-x^4 + o(x^4)$, $\cos^2(1-\cos^2(1-\cos^2(x))) = 1-x^8+o(x^8)$, etc. But this does not change the main question: before considering the limit (or any property, really) of a function,  the very first step is to give a definition of this function, and to show it's a valid definition. As written above, it's not even clear syntactically how this numerator is defined, let alone whether the definition is mathematically valid.

Comment: see the problem in picture

Comment: The book's solution is of course wrong: you can't generally do something like
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)}{\sin g(x)}=
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)}{\sin\bigl(\lim\limits_{x\to0}g(x)\bigr)}
$$
like they do.

Answer (score 3):

$$
\frac{\sqrt{4+x}-2}x=\frac1{\sqrt{4+x}+2}
$$

If the numerator is the limit of the fixed point iteration of $f(u)=\cos^2(1-u)$ then it should be helpful to attempt to show that the unique (positive) fixed point is $u=1$, which should be easy since $1-f(u)=\sin^2(1-u)\le\sin(1)(1-u)$ for all $u\in [0,1]$.

To make it formally correct write the numerator as $f^\infty(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}f^n(x)$ where $f^n$ is the $n$-fold composition of $f$ with itself. Since $f(x)\in[0,1]$ and $f$ is contractive there, $ f^\infty\equiv 1$ is a constant function.

Comment: I'm not the OP, but I have a small question here, if the numerator has 2, or 3, or even a billion of iterations of $f$, its limit is still 1. Can the numerator have infinitely many iterations of $f$? And should its limit still be 1 in this case?

Answer (score 1):

The numerator is $\cos^2\left(\sin^2\left(\sin^2\left(\dots\sin^2(x)\right)\right)\right)$ which tends to $1$ as $x\to0$.

The denominator is $\sin\left(\pi\frac{\sqrt{4+x}-2}{x}\right)=\sin\left(\pi\frac1{\sqrt{4+x}+2}\right)$ which tends to $\sin\left(\frac\pi4\right)=\frac1{\sqrt2}$ as $x\to0$.

The ratio, therefore, tends to $\sqrt2$.